# Zend Guard on Mac OSX 10.8.4

Tags: zend-guard

I have installed Zend Guard on Mac OSX 10.8.4, but when I start it, I get the following Java error message:

> An error has occured. See the log file /Application/Zend Guard ...

Here is the log file:

http://pastebin.com/BLr1Bqxh

I have no idea what to do. The ini of Zend Guar looks like this:

> -d32
>   -vmargs
>   -Xdock:icon=../Resources/guard_icon.icns
>   -XstartOnFirstThread
>   -Xbootclasspath/p:../../../plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.2.0.v20060605/jdi.jar
>   -Xms40m
>   -Xmx256m
>   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
>   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.noFocusRing

Comment: it'll be nice if you used a pastie/pastebin for long error outputs

Comment: Sorry! Edited, next time I will know it better :)